# How can I dynamically schedule some serial and some parallel tasks in groovy?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have some code that dynamically schedules a bunch of test jobs in parallel. It looks like

```
config.deploymentTargets.each { deploymentName ->
   config.deploymentTargetsMap[deploymentName][branchName].each { deploymentTargetName ->
      def testContext = "${stageName}.${deploymentTargetName}"
      deployments[testContext] = {
         stage( textContext ) {
            /* set up one test */
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In some cases, we have 10-12 of these tests running at once, but the number of such tests is dynamic. I'd like to change that so that they run in "batches" of three, so tests 1, 2, 3 run serially as "test suite 1", tests 4, 5, 6 run serially as "test suite 2", and so on. Then the different "test suites" can run in parallel. How can I restructure the groovy code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In the modified code, i create a `testSuites` array to store all the test contexts. Then, i iterate over the `testSuites` array using `eachWithIndex`, and based on the `batchSize` value, i calculate the batch number for each test suite.

i've created a `parallelStages` map to store the stages for each batch. If a batch doesn't exist in the `parallelStages` map, i've created an empty map for it. Then add the test suite as a key within the respective batch, and assign the stage definition as its value.

Finally, in the `node` block, i've a stage named `"Parallel Test Suites"` where use the parallel step and pass the `parallelStages` map to run the test suites in parallel according to the defined batches.

With this restructuring, the tests will run serially within each batch (three at a time), and the different test suites will run in parallel.

I've tried modify your code:

```
def batchSize = 3 // Number of tests to run in each batch

def testSuites = []
config.deploymentTargets.each { deploymentName ->
  config.deploymentTargetsMap[deploymentName][branchName].each { deploymentTargetName ->
    def testContext = "${stageName}.${deploymentTargetName}"
    testSuites.add(testContext)
  }
}

def parallelStages = [:]
testSuites.eachWithIndex { testSuite, index ->
  def batchNumber = (index / batchSize) + 1
  if (!parallelStages["Batch ${batchNumber}"]) {
    parallelStages["Batch ${batchNumber}"] = {}
  }
  parallelStages["Batch ${batchNumber}"][testSuite] = {
    stage(testSuite) {
      /* set up one test */
    }
  }
}

node {
  stage("Parallel Test Suites") {
    parallel parallelStages
  }
}
```